# How to save and restore the association of a window to buffer across Emacs sessions?

Tags: buffers, window, desktop, window-configuration

I have a window layout with three windows and I would like Emacs to remember the buffers even if the buffers don't exist after restart.

Context: I am using Spacemacs for Clojure development. In window #1 I have my sourcecode. In window #2 I have `*cider/repl ...`, which is my REPL which is only available after starting it. In window #3 I have `*cider-test-report*` which is my unit test report. Since the buffers in #2 and #3 are temporary, Emacs fills them with `*scratch*` after restart.

How to get Emacs to open my usual buffers in windows as soon as the buffers are available?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current window configuration (as well as other features of your current Emacs session) using `M-x desktop-save`.

As node [Saving Emacs Sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) of the Emacs manual tells you:

> You can also enable automatic saving of the desktop when you exit Emacs, and automatic restoration of the last saved desktop when Emacs starts: use the Customization buffer (*note Easy Customization::) to set `desktop-save-mode` to `t` for future sessions, or add this line
>   in your init file (*note Init File::):

```
 (desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The REPL and test window open with `*scratch*` after restart and don't change after I connect the REPL.